# New Facebook Pages, the admins don't see the timeline

Tags: facebook, admin, facebook-page, facebook-timeline

I updated to news Fan Pages and the admins don't see the timeline. They only see the header and don't have options.

Currents users can see everything and publish actualizations but not the admins.

Comment: Admin questions should be directed to http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbDevelopers rather than on Stackoverflow where we deal with issues you're having with your code.

Answer (score 0):

it's repaired automatically. When i updated New Facebook Pages, the admins don´t see the timeline but toda